# Window with bottom bar

Tags: user-interface, cross-platform, electron

In Electron, is there a way to put a "bottom bar" (under MacOS, "status bar" under Windows) into a window? More specifically, I'm looking for a (cross-platform) alternative to Cocoa's:

```
[theWindow setContentBorderThickness:24.0 forEdge:NSMinYEdge];
```

which looks like:

[image: bottom bar]

Answer (score 0):

The most crossplatform solution is to make your window framless https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md this allows you to define the window controlls via HTML and CSS without bothering with platform specific styling. But it also means you need to code the functionality.

Comment: Sry for the late response, you'll need to hook into the API somehow, here is an article on how to do it for Windows https://felixrieseberg.com/using-native-windows-features-from-electron/ it should probably be the same on macOS.